# getting result from Vowpal Wabbit daemon mode

Tags: php, machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am running VW in daemon mode. As a standalone executable, it runs perfectly fine. In daemon mode, I see something about predictions and options initially but not the end result. Not sure what exactly is going on.

This is how I call VW6

```
/bin64/vw --daemon --num_children 2 -t -i ~/modelbow.vw6 --min_prediction 0 --max_prediction 1 -p stdout  2>&1
```

I check vw6 is running fine. I send data using simple php script (removed debug lines for brevity):

```
     $fp = fsockopen("localhost",26542, $errno, $errstr, 3);
     $fp_dat = fopen("/tmp/ml.dat", "r");

     $mldata = explode("\n", file_get_contents("/tmp/ml.dat"));

     $mlstr = implode($mldata);

     fwrite($fp, $mlstr);

     $result = trim(fgets($fp, 1024));
     print $result;
```

Print $result above prints nothing. The only thing I see in stdout is

```
num sources = 1
Num weight bits = 28
learning rate = 10
initial_t = 1
power_t = 0.5
decay_learning_rate = 1
predictions = stdout
only testing
average    since       example  example    current  current  current
loss       last        counter   weight      label  predict features
```

While in a standalone executable mode, if I run with the same model same dat file just without the -daemon option, it happily gives a result at the end

```
...
...
predictions = stdout
only testing
average    since       example  example    current  current  current
loss       last        counter   weight      label  predict features
1.000000 ba66dfc7a135e2728d08010b40586b90
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here with the daemon mode? I tried using -p  /tmp/ option as well...ran the daemon mode with sudo but nothing helped.  Is there a debug dump option or verbose option or something else to know what exactly is going on?

thanks

Comment: Just added a tested/working example to the vw wiki at: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/daemon-example  The reason your code doesn't work may be a buffering issue in PHP.  This example  (sorry, not PHP) demonstrates that writing and reading from the same socket "just works." HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not working is not in `vw` but in the PHP client code.

`explode` on "\n", strips the newlines out.

`implode` without a glue-string parameter results in glue-string defaulting to the empty string.

Result: newlines are stripped out.
All examples are merged into one big (and incomplete, since there's no newline at the end) example.

`vw` needs newlines to separate examples, without them it will be waiting forever for the 1st example to complete.

So I think you need to change the implode line of code to:

> `$mlstr = implode("\n", $mldata);`

for it to work.

You will also need an additional ending newline to get the last line through.